# Should bypass valve on water softener be turn off every time you shut the water to the house?

Tags: plumbing

I am a plumber and need to change the water heater. I always turn off the bypass valve of the water softener before I shut off the water to the house. I just need to know if this step is necessary or could it harm the water softener in any way. Should the bypass valve on the water softener be turn off every time I shut off the water to the house?

Thank you.

Comment: If you are a plumber you would not have to ask.

Answer (score 1):

My only concern would be if you are doing some work UPSTREAM from the softener that might create or dislodge some debris, then switching to bypass will prevent that from messing up the works of the softener.